# Printing linked list print only last node

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, nodes

I would be happy if you can help me understand Why the next problem happens: When I print all the parts I made at my list its printed only the last element. I would be happy if you could tell me why this is happening and how to fix it.

my Constructors -

```
BankAccount::BankAccount(std::string name)
: _name(std::move(name))
, _balance()
{ }

LimitedBankAccount::LimitedBankAccount(double limit, std::string name)
: BankAccount(std::move(name))
, _limit(limit)
,a(NULL)
{ }

// call to my Constructors
void LimitedBankAccount::NewLimitedBankAccount(double limit, std::string name)
{
this->a = new LimitedBankAccount(limit,name);
}
```

my limited account .h -

```
#ifndef LIMITEDBANKACCOUNT_H
#define LIMITEDBANKACCOUNT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "BankAccount.h"

class LimitedBankAccount : public BankAccount{

public:

LimitedBankAccount(double limit, std::string _name);
void setLimit(double num);
double getLimit();

void NewLimitedBankAccount(double limit, std::string name);
void print();

private:

double _limit;
LimitedBankAccount* a;

 };

#endif
```

print function -

```
void LimitedBankAccount::print()
{
if(a != NULL)
{
    this->a->print();
}
std::cout << this->_limit << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks to all helpers !!

Comment: please provide a complete example. Most likely it prints the last element, because `a` is NULL and that's all...

Comment: Where do you call print() ?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to chain-link your objects; everytime you call NewLimitedBankAccount() you overwrite this->a, loosing the link to the previous object (so you leak memory as well). You should copy the pointer to your new object:

```
void LimitedBankAccount::NewLimitedBankAccount(double limit, std::string name)
{
   NewLimitedBankAccount *na = new LimitedBankAccount(limit,name);
   na->a = this->a;
   this->a = na;
}
```

This is really linked-lists 101....  And yes, the above will work for the first allocated object, when this->a is initially NULL.